# Bitwise expansion in C++

Tags: c++, int, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

here is my problem.
I have two short ints in C++:

```
short a;
short b;
```

Their bit representation can be put in the form

```
a = a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 ... a15
b = b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 ... b15
```

Where a0, b0, a1, b1 and so on represent the single bits for the two short ints.
Now, I would like to know if there is an efficient way to produce an int in the form:

```
a0 b0 a1 b1 a2 b2 ... a15 b15
```

I know I could pedantically use a loop and manually bitmasking every single bit, but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Thank you very much

Comment: They need to be `unsigned` short so you can use all the bits.  Otherwise, some of the bits will be used for the sign.

Comment: To be pedantic, you should label the bits the other way around: `a = a15 a14 a13...a2 a1 a0` (the last, least significant digit represents `2^0` and the first, most significant digit, represents `2^15` in a 16-bit __unsigned__ integer).

Comment: You are right! ;) Yeah sorry I meant to use an unsigned int of course!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way, with a lookup table:

```
static const unsigned short MortonTable256[256] = 
{
  0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0004, 0x0005, 0x0010, 0x0011, 0x0014, 0x0015, 
  0x0040, 0x0041, 0x0044, 0x0045, 0x0050, 0x0051, 0x0054, 0x0055, 
  0x0100, 0x0101, 0x0104, 0x0105, 0x0110, 0x0111, 0x0114, 0x0115, 
  0x0140, 0x0141, 0x0144, 0x0145, 0x0150, 0x0151, 0x0154, 0x0155, 
  0x0400, 0x0401, 0x0404, 0x0405, 0x0410, 0x0411, 0x0414, 0x0415, 
  0x0440, 0x0441, 0x0444, 0x0445, 0x0450, 0x0451, 0x0454, 0x0455, 
  0x0500, 0x0501, 0x0504, 0x0505, 0x0510, 0x0511, 0x0514, 0x0515, 
  0x0540, 0x0541, 0x0544, 0x0545, 0x0550, 0x0551, 0x0554, 0x0555, 
  0x1000, 0x1001, 0x1004, 0x1005, 0x1010, 0x1011, 0x1014, 0x1015, 
  0x1040, 0x1041, 0x1044, 0x1045, 0x1050, 0x1051, 0x1054, 0x1055, 
  0x1100, 0x1101, 0x1104, 0x1105, 0x1110, 0x1111, 0x1114, 0x1115, 
  0x1140, 0x1141, 0x1144, 0x1145, 0x1150, 0x1151, 0x1154, 0x1155, 
  0x1400, 0x1401, 0x1404, 0x1405, 0x1410, 0x1411, 0x1414, 0x1415, 
  0x1440, 0x1441, 0x1444, 0x1445, 0x1450, 0x1451, 0x1454, 0x1455, 
  0x1500, 0x1501, 0x1504, 0x1505, 0x1510, 0x1511, 0x1514, 0x1515, 
  0x1540, 0x1541, 0x1544, 0x1545, 0x1550, 0x1551, 0x1554, 0x1555, 
  0x4000, 0x4001, 0x4004, 0x4005, 0x4010, 0x4011, 0x4014, 0x4015, 
  0x4040, 0x4041, 0x4044, 0x4045, 0x4050, 0x4051, 0x4054, 0x4055, 
  0x4100, 0x4101, 0x4104, 0x4105, 0x4110, 0x4111, 0x4114, 0x4115, 
  0x4140, 0x4141, 0x4144, 0x4145, 0x4150, 0x4151, 0x4154, 0x4155, 
  0x4400, 0x4401, 0x4404, 0x4405, 0x4410, 0x4411, 0x4414, 0x4415, 
  0x4440, 0x4441, 0x4444, 0x4445, 0x4450, 0x4451, 0x4454, 0x4455, 
  0x4500, 0x4501, 0x4504, 0x4505, 0x4510, 0x4511, 0x4514, 0x4515, 
  0x4540, 0x4541, 0x4544, 0x4545, 0x4550, 0x4551, 0x4554, 0x4555, 
  0x5000, 0x5001, 0x5004, 0x5005, 0x5010, 0x5011, 0x5014, 0x5015, 
  0x5040, 0x5041, 0x5044, 0x5045, 0x5050, 0x5051, 0x5054, 0x5055, 
  0x5100, 0x5101, 0x5104, 0x5105, 0x5110, 0x5111, 0x5114, 0x5115, 
  0x5140, 0x5141, 0x5144, 0x5145, 0x5150, 0x5151, 0x5154, 0x5155, 
  0x5400, 0x5401, 0x5404, 0x5405, 0x5410, 0x5411, 0x5414, 0x5415, 
  0x5440, 0x5441, 0x5444, 0x5445, 0x5450, 0x5451, 0x5454, 0x5455, 
  0x5500, 0x5501, 0x5504, 0x5505, 0x5510, 0x5511, 0x5514, 0x5515, 
  0x5540, 0x5541, 0x5544, 0x5545, 0x5550, 0x5551, 0x5554, 0x5555
};

unsigned short x; // Interleave bits of x and y, so that all of the
unsigned short y; // bits of x are in the even positions and y in the odd;
unsigned int z;   // z gets the resulting 32-bit Morton Number.

z = MortonTable256[y >> 8]   << 17 | 
    MortonTable256[x >> 8]   << 16 |
    MortonTable256[y & 0xFF] <<  1 | 
    MortonTable256[x & 0xFF];
```

The lookup table converts the 8-bit binary number `abcdefgh` to `0a0b0c0d0e0f0g0h`. The code works for 16-bit inputs (and 32-bit output), but can be easily generalised for wider inputs.

The code is taken from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableLookup). See the link for two other methods.

For background, this interleaving of bits is called the [Morton code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) and is a way to combine multiple dimensions into one while preserving locality of points.

Comment: @Daniel every entry in the table is the "expanded" form of its index. So to expand a byte, you just use it as an index into that table. The `y`'s are then shifted left by 1 to make the bits fall in the slots left open in the `x`'s.

Comment: As far as I can tell, in this solution, the most significant bit of x becomes the least significant bit of z -- doesn't it? The result is basically reversed..

Comment: @Weston: I am not sure how you've reached this conclusion, but I am not seeing it. To my eye it's pretty clear that no bit orderings get reversed.

Comment: Yeah, combining multiple dimensions into one was exactly what I needed to do actually! I just didn't know that it was called Morton code!

Comment: @NPE: Sorry about that, I guess it was late when I wrote that.. :) Run your example code with x=0x000F and y=0. Then x (1111) and y (0000) gets merged into 01010101 (leading zeroes omitted). The original problem description specified that the result should be 10101010.

Comment: @Weston: `x` is `b` and `y` is `a`.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a `for` loop and get the algorithm working.

```
uint32_t result = 0;
uint16_t a;
uint16_t b;

const unsigned int bits_to_process = 16;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bits_to_process; ++i)
{
  result = a & 1;
  result << 1;
  result = b & 1;
  result << 1;
  a = a >> 1;
  b = b >> 1;
}
```

Once your code works correctly, turn up the optimization level.  The compiler may perform some amazing optimizations, like loop unrolling.

You could also search the web for "bit twiddling" and see if any of those cases are like yours.

Comment: This is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

inline unsigned int
move_bit(unsigned short x, int pos, int count)
{
    return (x & (1 << pos)) << count;
}

inline unsigned int
merge_bits(unsigned short a, unsigned short b)
{
    unsigned int res{};

    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        res |= (move_bit(a, i, i+1) | move_bit(b, i, i));

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned short a = 0xabcd;
    unsigned short b = 0x1234;
    unsigned int   c = merge_bits(a, b);

    cout << "a:      " << bitset<16>(a) << endl
         << "b:      " << bitset<16>(b) << endl
         << "merged: " << bitset<32>(c) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a:      1010101111001101
b:      0001001000110100
merged: 10001001100011101010010110110010
```